# Dependency injection for Automapper - AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 'Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.'

Tags: c#

When I run this line of code `var flattenedIncident = _mapper.Map<FlattenedIncident>(incident);`, it breaks with this exception

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 'Missing type map configuration
> or unsupported mapping.'

Previously, I am using Console project (without dependency injection) and I can run that line without issue.

These are some of my code

```
var mapperConfig = AutoMapperConfig.ConfigureMappings();
IMapper mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();

// code removed for brevity
var flattenedIncident = mapper.Map<FlattenedIncident>(incident); // this way works
```

Then I refactored my code to move my service layer (which include the above code) to the API project and used dependency injection to create the mapper instance.

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{        
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    
    public ServiceCloudSqlService(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;         
    }

    public async Task Update()
    {
        //    var mapperConfig = AutoMapperConfig.ConfigureMappings();
        //    IMapper mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();

        // code removed for brevity
        var flattenedIncident = _mapper.Map<FlattenedIncident>(incident); // this way doesn't works. Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
    }
}
```

And this is how I call the service layer from Console project.

```
public interface IConsoleApp
{
    void Run(string[] args);
}

public class ConsoleApp : IConsoleApp
{
    private readonly IMyService _myService;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public ConsoleApp(IMyService myService, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _myService = myService;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public void Run(string[] args)
    {            
        _myService.Update();                        
    }
}
```

and in Console project program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
        var consoleApp = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConsoleApp>();
        consoleApp.Run(args);
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program).Assembly);
                services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
                services.AddScoped<IConsoleApp, ConsoleApp>();
            });
}
```

and here are other codes which never changed

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static MapperConfiguration ConfigureMappings()
    {
        return new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {     
            cfg.AddProfile<IncidentProfile>();    
        });
    }
}

public class IncidentProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public IncidentProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Incident, FlattenedIncident>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program).Assembly);
try services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(IncidentProfile));

Comment: Thanks. It works. @Dušan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your host builder, when configuring AutoMapper, you should specify which assembly contains your mapping profile(s).

Replace `services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program).Assembly);`
with
`services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(IncidentProfile));`

Read more [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html).